# Devexpress textbox loses focus after OSK opens

Tags: c#, winforms, process, devexpress, web-operating-system

I have a devexpress textbox in a usercontrol in winforms application.
The problem is, when the usercontrol is loaded, and user clicks on the devexpress textbox, which in turn calls for OSK keyboard, loses focus from the textbox.

The user cannot directly start typing on OSK. Instead he needs to click on the textbox to gain focus back again and start typing.

Please suggest if there is any solution for this.

What I have found through debugging is, when I place a breakpoint on the set focus code, the focus is assigned to the textbox. But when I try to run it in a single go, it doesnot set the focus.

```
 private void OnMouseClickUserControl(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //  verify if the button is displayed
            if (!this.ShowButton)
            {               
                this.OnEnterUserControl(this, e);               
            }

        }


private void OnEnterUserControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //  verify if button is displayed
            if (!this.ShowButton)
            {
                //  set the input scope
                this.SetInputScope();
                //  show the keyboard
                TabTip.OpenTabTip();

                //  focus the helper textbox
                //this.tbxText.Focus();

                this.tbxText.SelectAll();
                this.tbxText.SelectionLength = 0;


            }
        }

 public static bool OpenTabTip()        
        {
            bool result = false;

            //  reset the main window handle 
            TabTip._keyboardMainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

string osk = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "system32"), "osk.exe");
                string pathX64 = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramW6432%");
                string pathX32 = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%");
                //  in case of 32 bit systems
                if (osk.Contains(pathX32))
                    osk = osk.Replace(pathX32, pathX64);
                //  start the keyboard process
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(osk);                
                Process tmp = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);

                //  wait until starting the process has been finished
                //result = tmp.WaitForInputIdle(5000);
                //  refresh the process information
                tmp.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Do you get this same result using a standard WinForms UserControl and TextBox control?

Comment: no, a standard WinForms UserControl and TextBox works fine, the problem is with Devexpress control